# Работа с интерфейсом retrofit android для логина

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Я уже задал много вопросов по созданию приложения с функцией логина, одним из этапов создания такого приложения является создание interface для корректной работы, сначала я использовал такой интерфейс:

```
@POST("/{login}/{password}")
Call<LoginRequest> savePost(@Field("id") Integer id, @Field("password") String password);
```

потом я узнал что на сервере от меня ждут чистый json а так я отправляю форму на сервер, и я начал использовать такой код для интерфейса:

```
@POST("/{login}/{password}")
Call<LoginRequest> savePost(@Body LoginRequest body);
```

и у меня после замены первого варианта на второй студия ругается на метод savepost:

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-11 03:38:27.598 25289-25289/com.example.developer_4.test_log E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_log, PID: 25289
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
        for method APIService.savePost
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:743)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:761)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:351)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:204)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
        at $Proxy0.savePost(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_log.LoginActivity.sendPost(LoginActivity.java:135)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_log.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:108)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

приведенная строка:

```
mAPIService.savePost(id, password).enqueue(new Callback<LoginRequest>()
```

Вы можете увидеть мои предыдущие вопросы, и уже у меня вроде начало все немного работать но теперь я запутался и остались проблемы с конвертацией данных из полей ввода в json. Если кто знает как мне помочь буду очень благодарен.

Comment: `@POST("/{login}/{password}")` - вот это исправьте на правильный путь логина или добавьте соответствующие параметры с аннотацией `@Path`

Comment: правильный путь это адрес сервера? если да то нужно ли вытирать в конце слово login или нужно вставлять полностью https://сервер/v1/login ?

Comment: Какой Вам дали адрес такой и пишите. Только путь указывается относительно `baseUrl` - то есть если `.baseUrl("http://exemple.com")`, а адрес запроса `http://exemple.com/v1/login`, то путь будет `@POST("/v1/login")`

Comment: Возможно не тот Body импорировали - по кажите import код

Comment: та у меня вроде уже пропала эта ошибка зато вылезла другая)) спасибо.